# Adding info to a database with php

Tags: php, sql, database

Hi there doing a small project with databases ( don't have too much experience with them). I'm working with mySQL and php, having a little bit of trouble with the php and posting the info from the HTML form to the database.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tags"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.  
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");   
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get data that sent from form 
$s_name=$_GET['name'];
$s_system=$_GET['system'];
$s_cate=$_GET['cate'];

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name,system,cate)VALUES('$s_name', '$s_system', '$s_cate')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "Successful<BR>";
echo "<a href=mainforum.php>View your topic</a>";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

If anyone could help explain to me what I am doing wrong, much would very be appreciated.

THANKS

Here is a link to what I am trying to do:

http://socialsoftware.purchase.edu/roger-p.king/database2/enter_gamertag.html

Comment: Try printing the values of `$s_name` and `$sql` to see what they contain.

Comment: I'd say the first way to check if this is writing is to, like AJ said, echo $sql, then copy what it prints into your MySQL query screen and see if you get an error or not. This way you'll know whether the error is with your INSERT query, or if it is elsewhere.

This is usually how I debug my queries...Also you can combine the two echos in the if($result) to echo "Successful<BR> <a href....>, but you probably know this already

Comment: Can you show what is the error is?

Comment: put $tbl_name in single quotes in sql query

Comment: I tried to echo the $s_name and the $sql. it only prints the $sql but not the names that are inputted in the form.

Comment: INSERT INTO 'tags'('name','system','cate')VALUES('', '', '')ERROR 

that is what gets printed on the screen when echo $s_name and $sql... it doesn't print the name.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

u should use $_POST['variable'], not $_GET

because $_GET is variables array on the link

such as "http://example.com/?var=123", the value of $_GET['var'] is 123

the variable in form can get by $_POST['var'] or $_REQUEST['var']

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using GET. Unless he is using it for sending sensitive informations, it is ok to use GET.

Comment: its not necessarily an error message its just when you submit the forum, it takes the if else statement check and doesn't post what is inputed in the form

Answer (score 0):

`$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO '$tbl_name'(name,system,cate)VALUES('$s_name', '$s_system', '$s_cate')";`

That should do, or if you do it your way in 2 lines,

`$sql="INSERT INTO '$tbl_name'(name,system,cate)VALUES('$s_name', '$s_system', '$s_cate')";`

`$result=mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: I just tried this and it still doesn't work. still giving else statement error.

Comment: Could it be the way I created the fields on phpmyadmin?

Comment: its not necessarily an error message its just when you submit the forum, it takes the if else statement check and doesn't post what is inputed in the form. and it will print the 'Error' that is in the else statement